# I use lazynvim but the plugin eslint_d doesn't take into account my .eslintrc.js file

Tags: eslint, neovim, eslintrc

i'm using lazynvim, i have a node js project using the eslint_d but it formats the wrong way without taking account my .eslintrc.js.

Could you help me please ?

Thanks

I've tried uninstalling the plugin and using a different one like eslint-lsp